# Using Autofac for DI into WCF service hosted in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, wcf, autofac

I'm having trouble injecting services dependencies into my WCF service using Autofac 1.4.5. I've read and followed the [Autofac wiki page on WcfIntegration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration) but my debugging shows me that my WCF service is created by the `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.GetInstance()` method and not by the `AutofacWebServiceHostFactory`. What am I doing wrong?

I've set up my `ajax.svc` file to look like the one in the example for use with `WebHttpBinding`:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="Generic.Frontend.Web.Ajax, Generic.Frontend.Web"
    Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacWebServiceHostFactory,
             Autofac.Integration.Wcf" %>
```

My WCF service class `Ajax` is defined like this:

```
namespace Generic.Frontend.Web
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
        RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Ajax
    {
        public MapWebService MapWebService { get; set;}

        public Ajax() {
            // this constructor is being called
        }

        public Ajax(MapWebService mapWebService)
        {
            // this constructor should be called
            MapWebService = mapWebService;
        }

        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract(Name = "mapchange")]
        public MapChangeResult ProcessMapChange(string args)
        {
            // use the injected service here
            var result = MapWebService.ProcessMapChange(args);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I've used the wiring up in the `Global.asax.cs` as shown in the wiki mentioned above:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModuleWebservice());
var container = builder.Build();
AutofacServiceHostFactory.Container = container;
```

with

```
class AutofacModuleWebservice : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register<Ajax>();
        builder.Register<MapWebService>().ContainerScoped();
    }
}
```

In my web.config I have

```
<services>
    <service name="Generic.Frontend.Web.Ajax">
        <endpoint address="http://mysite.com/ajax.svc/" binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="Generic.Frontend.Web.Ajax" />
    </service>
</services>
```

.

The service already works fine but I can't get the Autofac bits (read: creation/injection) to work. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Removing the default constructor unfortunately leads to the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not
have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default
constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.
```

Cheers, Oliver

Comment: Did you solve this? I have a similar problem and I have asked my question here ->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489403/using-autofac-with-ajax-enabled-wcf-service

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's also the reason why there's nothing marked as answer, here :-|

Comment: How do you host it? iis, was, selfhosting? You should write that down in your question I think. You write different code depending on this.

Comment: @Johan: It's hosted in IIS.

Comment: Following the instructions solved it for me: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration#IIS_Hosted_Services I simply do : builder.RegisterType<SomeService>(); and I've followed their instuructions for changing the .svc file. When you look at your .svc file you do not get any hints about something being wrong there btw? You host it throu the iis and no was code, I do not see your code for overriding global.asax.cs

Answer (score 1):

Is your service setup with InstanceContextMode.Single?  If it is then wcf will create your service using the default constructor.  To get around this change your instance context mode and let autofac manage the lifetime of your service.

Comment: Hi Jon, no it's not setup with InstanceContextMode.Single. I also tried setting it to PerSession explicitely - to no effect.

Comment: It can also be a base class that's configured with InstanceContextMode.Single (that was my case)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the default `Ajax` constructor and modifying your constructor to this. If it gets run with `mapWebService == null` that would indicate a resolution problem.

```
    public Ajax(MapWebService mapWebService = null)
    {
        // this constructor should be called
        MapWebService = mapWebService;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I had actually already tried that to the effect of receiving the following System.InvalidOperationException: The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host. That's how I figured that Autofac was actually not creating the service instance.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same System.InvalidOperationException and solved it by changing the ServiceBehavior InstanceContextMode of the implementation from InstanceContextMode.PerCall to InstanceContextMode.PerSession, perhaps your AutoFac lifetime scope is out of sync with your web service implementation?

For testing AutoFac service creation I recommend creating a unit test and directly resolving them as this will highlight any issues and give more meaningful exception messages. For services with a request lifetime scope create a test aspx page and again resolve them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came across this question while searching for an answer.

In my case, using property injection worked, and the code in the question already has a property that can be used:

```
namespace Generic.Frontend.Web
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
        RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Ajax
    {
        // inject the dependency here
        public MapWebService MapWebService { get; set;}

        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract(Name = "mapchange")]
        public MapChangeResult ProcessMapChange(string args)
        {
            // use the injected service here
            var result = MapWebService.ProcessMapChange(args);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

and register to use property injection (sample code from the wiki and syntax has changed as this is now using version 2.5.2.830):

```
builder.RegisterType<Ajax>().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions solved it for me:

code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/… I simply do : builder.RegisterType();

and I've followed their instuructions for changing the .svc file.

When you look at your .svc file you do not get any hints about something being wrong there btw?

You host it throu the iis and do not utilize WAS, I do not see your code for overriding global.asax.cs

Add the global file to your solution and there you implement:

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // build and set container in application start
            IContainer container = AutofacContainerBuilder.BuildContainer();
            AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;


        }
```

AutofacContainerBuilder is my container builder.